# Sharing photo at xml view

Tags: android

i want to share a photo that is at my xml view but any sharing intenet requires that photo should be saved on memory card. how can i use that photo?

this is my xml:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ellyfish" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

First get the bitmap from imageview:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Create a new file using this bitmap:

```
public File createImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
File f ;        
try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        // you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "rwd_temp.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        // write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
    }
        return f;
}
```

What I am doing is getting the bitmap from the imageview and saving that bitmap in a file named rwd_temp.jpg. After you have the file you can upload it to server or share it.
You will require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for this.

Comment: im new at programming can u explain more? hoe can i save imageview at sd card?

Comment: @user3118791 you are not saving an imageview you are saving the content of imageview(the image) which is represented as a Bitmap in android in a file.

Comment: at the first line where should i put id of my imageview?